# Factory reset is disabled by kill switch on LG L16C

Tags: factory-reset, lg

I cannot do a factory reset on a LGL16c, it comes up with screen to confirm reset and agreeing to wipe data, I say yes to both. Then it comes up with a screen that says

> Factory reset is disabled by **Kill switch**

I reboots and nothing happens. I cannot reset through settings on phone, security, it says factory reset disabled by server policy.

I found out that all new smartphones have this new "Kill switch" installed by all manufacturers because a new law passed prevents a thief from accessing a phone if there is a password on it and trying to factory reset it.

Is there a way to bypass the kill switch if I have the phone and there is no password and I want to wipe data and reset phone?

Comment: You would have to enable debugging in developer options, hook it to a PC,  flash a custom recovery, and flash another ROM. There are other steps to disable the KillSwitch, but I will not post those steps on a public site because of illegal activity that can be done using those steps.

Comment: Related on XDA: [LG G3 locked by Mcafee (kill switch)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/lg-g3-locked-mcafee-kill-switch-t3015110) and [AndroidCommunity](http://androidcommunity.com/mcafee-brings-kill-switch-feature-to-lg-g3-phones-20140613/)

Answer (score 1):

"Killswitch" wouldn't allow me to turn on my usb debugging yet, I was able to bypass "Killswitch" by using [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and wipe my phone as if it was lost or stolen. Which in turn reset the phone "LG L16C".

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that [newer smartphones are neccesary to have anti-theft kill switch](http://androidcommunity.com/ctia-announces-smartphone-anti-theft-voluntary-commitment-kill-switch-policy-20140415/), this particular kill switch on LG devices were installed by McAfee. From [Android Community](http://androidcommunity.com/mcafee-brings-kill-switch-feature-to-lg-g3-phones-20140613/)

> LG Electronics announced that it has partnered with McAfee to bring an anti-theft feature to the new LG G3 phones. The mobile devices will now be pre-installed with the latest version of the **McAfee Mobile Security, which includes a Kill Switch function** so that you can erase data and disable the phones when it has fallen into the wrong hands.
>
> Not only will the software protect the LG G3 from these malware infections, **it also has a kill switch that will enable you to disable your phone’s functions, including unauthorised factory reset**, when it gets stolen. Even attempts to root the phone will be blocked and the lock screen will require password authentication, and the user can control the device from a web console.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

From [XDA Forum post by twisted_twice](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64292810&postcount=18),

[image: Kill switch's operations for each scenario table]

it seems you have to either:

- Turn off **Lock Down Device** on McAfee: you can then initiate factory reset, but you may be asked for PIN after that, or
- Unregister your device on [McAfee Mobile Security](https://lge.mcafeemobilesecurity.com/) (not really recommended security-wise)

Comment: The default PIN is 123456.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have had a lot of experience with android devices, and I might have found a solution:

If your device is rooted, and you haven't already gotten your phone locked, you can get a ["bloatware" remover](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_456), find `com.android.systemUI.factory.KILLSWITCH.apk.ODEX` and remove it. I hope this works!

Comment: Are you sure on the file to remove? I just wonder about the `.apk.ODEX` extension. Usually, the app files (which is what those "bloatware removers" go after) have the extension `.apk` – while `.odex` files are the "Optimized Dalvik EXexutables". So could you please [edit] your post and include some background/details? Thanks in advance!