# Download mode disabled by kill switch on LG G3

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lg-g3

I have installed CyanogenMod 13 on my LG G3 (LG D850), but I decided to return back to stock ROM. I download the files, but when I try to install by download mode, it shows a message that download mode disabled by killswitch.

Regarding McAfee's killswitch, I'm using CyanogenMod ROM, and I believe it doesn't have McAfee as a preinstalled app.

How to fix this issue?

---

I am asking about third method so that I get some real thing to block this so called "kill switch"  :(

Comment: Ahmad, just to clarify: Are you sure you haven't installed that MacAffee app yourself? I'm sure it didn't come pre-installed with CM, but if you installed it manually, the effect would be the same. If you still can boot your device normally, make sure by checking *Settings › Apps* (on the "All" tab, to be absolutely sure) that it isn't shown.

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate, but refer to this similar issue with other LG phone: [Factory reset is disabled by kill switch on LG L16C](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124302/factory-reset-is-disabled-by-kill-switch-on-lg-l16c/)

Comment: I tried this method but McAfee says your device is unlocked :(

Answer (score 0):

This "issue" coused by McAffee (KillSwitch) which prevent hardreset or install a new rom on your phone.

So first, you have to boot up you device, open up McAffee app and disable it or just simply uninstall it if you can. After you will able to install the stock ROM.

Same issue is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/lg-g3-locked-mcafee-kill-switch-t3015110).

Comment: Where did OP mention having McAffee installed? (Note: Ahmad does *not* have it installed) And I've never heard CM included that in its ROMs.

Comment: Because only McAffee Mobile Security contains this feature "KillSwitch" which prevent to do FR or install a new ROM.  @Ahmad had to be installed McAffee and activate it to enable this option, there is no other way.

Comment: Yes. And how does it do that if it wasn't even installed on the device? Remote magic? So every phone in the world is affected, even if it never heard of that app? You'd have your point if OP had this app installed – but Ahmad explicitly points out he had ***not***. So this is an answer/solution to a *different* issue, but – no offense meant – not to this one here :)

Comment: If you Google to this keywords: "kill switch disable download mode" there is only hits which associated with enabled McAffee app. So there are 3 ways - 1st: The hits just wrong and all the comments are false, 2nd: the OP forget that he installed and enabled it on his device,  3rd: some reason not OP installed and enabled it on his device.

Comment: I guess we can rule out #1. You have your point with #2 (I've left a comment on the question for clarification: indeed Ahmad just stated it didn't come pre-installed, but said nothing about maybe having it installed himself). If that's ruled out as well, it leaves #3 (as I initially assumed). Let's see what Ahmad responds.

Comment: I didn't install it after zipping cm13 on my cell phone coz I jus hate McAfee as it hanged my PC once I installed it

Comment: So there is no other way left only #3.

Comment: I talked to McAfee service agent

Comment: He said he can't do anything coz this issue is handled by lg service and I told him that lg is not working in my country :(

Comment: I font understand #3

Comment: What's da procedure in #3

Comment: Try to summarize what you're trying to say in the future.

The procedure: as [linked](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124302/factory-reset-is-disabled-by-kill-switch-on-lg-l16c/) previously (@Andrew T.), follow [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64292810&postcount=18).